# Creating Textview without destroying my GUI

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am making an app for android, something like a cashbox for me and my girlfriend, where we can add bills from shopping or buying stuff for our appartement.

In the xml file of the MainActivity I already created three buttons for adding persons to the cashbox and some other stuff. Every time I add a new person to the cashbox, it should create a new textview within a new LinearLayout. But it moves my whole UI like in the picture.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showDiagram"
        android:text="@string/showDiagram"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addExpenditure"
        android:text="@string/addExpenditure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addResident"
        android:text="@string/addResident"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText residentName;
int numberOfRes = 0;
DataHandler db = new DataHandler(this);
boolean notShow;
Button add;
String name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button showDiagram = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDiagram);

    final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

    //Ausgabe hinzufügen
    Button addExpenditure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addExpenditure);
    addExpenditure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

    //Erstellung eines neuen Mitbewohners für die Kasse
    Button addResident = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addResident);
    addResident.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        final Dialog dialog = createDialog();

        residentName = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.residentname);

        add =(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                name = String.valueOf(residentName.getText());
                db.insert(name);
                dialog.dismiss();
                myLayout.addView(createResident(name));
                Log.d("debug","mylayout.addview() aufgerufen");
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

public Dialog createDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Dialog");
    return dialog;
}

public LinearLayout createResident(String name){
    LinearLayout newRes = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.5f);
    newRes.setLayoutParams(newParams);
    newRes.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    newRes.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


    TextView res = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newParamsRes = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.5f);
    res.setLayoutParams(newParamsRes);
    res.setText(name);
    res.setTextSize(25);
    res.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    newRes.addView(res);
    return newRes;
    }
}
```

Destroyed UI

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went for RelativeLayout instead, and it worked!